# How can I replace child components on the parent in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have read this official documentation on [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and also have tested the working of it, but I found out that it does not really match with my use case.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have 3 components: Login, Register and Forgot Password, which I
    would like to display somewhere in my landing web page.

1. First of all, I want to display the login component, and in login page users can navigate to other components by either clicking on the signup
   link or the forgot password link.
2. Second, I have implemented an interaction between the Login component and the parent app.component using [Event Emitter](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular) so the child and parent listen to each other.

Now my problem is that, when a user clicks on the signup link, the parent should receive the command and either remove the login component and replace the register component visa viz. I know it has to do with directive and component resolver but I can't help it at the moment. 
Please can someone guide me further.

Comment: I think you should use `router-outlet` in `app.component.html`. https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet

Comment: I have almost overlook your suggestion since i have not fully understand the SPA  working. Traditionally, every url will navigate a page and when i view the Live Preview, i thought it is behaving like that. Now i have got what i wanted by using the router-outlet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your app component would be like so:

```
//Appcomponent.ts
let state = ‘login’;

//appcomponent.html
<div *ngIf=“state === ‘login’”>
    <login (resetPW)=“state = ‘resetPW’”></login>
</div>
<div *ngIf=“state === ‘resetPW’”>
    ...
</div>
...
```

Then make an eventemitter from login component for resetPW

Comment: if both components access DB or perform intensive computations this will trigger both components to execute their respective computations?